# Are questions about the use of specific technologies in the cinema industry on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example, there was this question about [whether a movie was released in a certain format](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82825/has-justice-league-been-released-in-imax-3d). Turns out that IMAX is moving away from 3D screenings in the US (maybe globally). Definitely seems to be 100% about movies, though it seems to touch upon "Locating or purchasing Movies", but isn't really covered by it.

Just asking, because the question got at least 5 downvotes which confuses and surprises me.

And now it got closed as

> Recommendation questions asking for movies/TV-shows or resources to locate or watch movie/TV content are off topic.

which doesn't apply whatsoever to the question.

Comment: Pro-tip: don't ask questions that can be answered at face-value with a simple yes or no answer (even that's really incorrect).  Reword the question to ask WHY something is the way it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to your general question, **yes, *in general* questions pertaining to the use of specific cinema technology or the general release policies of movies for specific formats seems to be on-topic** (special cases notwithstanding), as also evidenced by many questions in e.g. the tags [imax](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imax), [distribution](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution), ...

As to the specific question you take as an example. That indeed seemed to be somewhat of an unfortunate case and people seemed to have interpreted it as looking for specific showtimes, rather than being a general question about the movie's distribution policy ([other examples](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27012/49) of which [worked very well](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45424/49) before), to which statements about the superiority of formats might have contributed, too (but I'm just guessing here).

Instead of cold-reopening right away, though, I tried to rephrase the question a little to clear the last possible misunderstandings, which apparently happened. I do agree that in this form it is quite a reasonable question and have no qualms with being the 4th and final reopen-voter (and upvoter).